# jVectorMap, store center coords before redraw the map

Tags: javascript, svg, jvectormap

I'm currently using jVectorMap to keep track of an app users activities.

Every time an user position is updated, the server fire an event and the client redraw the map.

I would like to keep track of last scale and coordinates values so that I can redraw the map in the same position and zoom instead of the default one.

I've already tried to use onViewportChange to store the scale value and pass it to the new map with focusOn and it works but i can't get any lat lng or x y values with that.

How can i get map's center coordinates or x y values? Any ideas?

Comment: how can I get x and y with `onViewportChange` ?